# Is it possible to slow down UIScrollView:scrollRectToVisible:'s animation?

Tags: ios

I'm using scrollRectToVisible: to animate a a carousel of images, however the change from one image to the other is a bit fast (this is with animation set to YES) and consequently seems a little jarring. 
Is it possible to slow it down so it scrolls from one image to another slower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
set [scrollRectToVisible:NO];
and implement it in using your customView animation UIView animateView methods.